# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent after tried to login

Tags: node.js, firebase, authentication, handlebars.js, response-headers

There are a lot of question with my issue but, I tried some of the solution and no one worked.

I'm getting the following error everytime I tried to do the login:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
>       at ServerResponse.header (/home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
>       at userService.checkUser (/home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/index.js:54:18)
>       at Object.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged.firebaseUser [as next] (/home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/auth.js:69:17)
>       at /home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1361:22
>       at /home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1465:21
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)

this is my index.js in node:

```
app.get('/user', (request, response) => {
    userService.checkUser( (firebaseUser) => {
        if (firebaseUser) {
            response.render('user', {firebaseUser});
        }else {
            // response.redirect('/');
            response.redirect('/');
        }
        response.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
        response.render('index');
    });

});


app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
 var userEmail = req.body.emailLogin;
 var userPassword = req.body.passwordLogin;
 console.log(userEmail, userPassword); //This log the email and the password

 userService.loginUser(
   userEmail,
   userPassword,

   (error, authData) => {
     if (error) {
       return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
     } else {
       res.redirect('/user');
       //console.log(authData);
       return authData
     }
   }
 );
});
```

and in auth.js I have :

```
function loginUser(email, password, callback) {
     console.log(email, password);
     firebase
       .auth()
       .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
       .then((firebaseUser) => {
         // Success
         console.log("Ok, lovely I'm logged");
         callback(null, firebaseUser);
         //console.log(firebaseUser);
         return firebaseUser
       })
       .catch((error) => {

         callback(error);
       });
   }


function checkUser( callback ) {
   firebase
       .auth()
       .onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
           if(firebaseUser) {
               // console.log(firebaseUser);
               callback(firebaseUser);
               return firebaseUser;
           } else {
               console.log('pp');
               callback(null);
               return firebaseUser;
           }

       });
}
```

So far if I run the server on my machine, the login works but I get anyway the error in my log, instead, if I deploy my project on firebase I can't use the login function.

Probably the problem is this error.

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong? Thankyou

***EDIT***

After aplying the @molda solution I'm getting:

> error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
>       at ServerResponse.header (/home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
>       at ServerResponse.location (/home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:884:15)
>       at ServerResponse.redirect (/home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:922:18)
>       at userService.checkUser (/home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/index.js:51:22)
>       at Object.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged.firebaseUser [as next] (/home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/auth.js:73:17)
>       at /home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1361:22
>       at /home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1465:21
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
>   127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2019:10:54:29 +0000] "GET /logout HTTP/1.1" 302 46 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 OPR/58.0.3135.127"
>   [hosting] Rewriting / to local function app
>   error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
>       at ServerResponse.header (/home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send (/home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
>       at done (/home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1004:10)
>       at /home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:876:7
>       at /home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:161:5
>       at Promise._execute (/home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:313:9)
>       at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:483:18)
>       at new Promise (/home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10)
>       at promisify (/home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:154:10)
>       at Function.exports.handlebars.render (/home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:866:10)
>       at /home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:181:27
>       at /home/ale/PycharmProjects/veople/webapp/functions/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:101:5
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)

***EDIT 2***

index.js:

```
function createDatauser(firebaseUid, name, lastname){
    const docRef = db.collection('users').doc(firebaseUid);

    const setData = docRef.set({
      first: name,
      last: lastname
    });
}

...

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    userService.checkUser( (firebaseUser) => {
        if (firebaseUser) {
            console.log(firebaseUser.email)
        }else {
            console.log('not logged in');
        }
        // response.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
        response.render('index', {firebaseUser});
    });



});



...

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
 const nameRegister = req.body.name;
    const surnameRegister = req.body.surname;
    const emailRegister = req.body.emailRegister;
    const passwordRegister = req.body.passwordRegister;
    const confirmPasswordRegister = req.body.confirmPasswordRegister;
    console.log(emailRegister, passwordRegister);

 userService.registerUser(
   emailRegister,
   passwordRegister,

   (error, authData) => {
     if (error) {
       return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
     } else {
       res.redirect('/user');
       console.log(authData);
       createDatauser(authData.user.uid, nameRegister, surnameRegister);
       return authData
     }
   }
 );
});

...

app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
 userService.logoutUser();
 res.redirect('/');

});
```

auth.js

```
function registerUser(email, password, callback) {
      console.log(email, password);
      firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((firebaseUser) => {
          // Success
          //console.log("Ok, lovely I'm registred", firebaseUser);
          callback(null, firebaseUser);
          return firebaseUser
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Error Handling
          // var errorCode = error.code;
          // var errorMessage = error.message;
          //console.log(errorCode); //auth/user-not-found
          //console.log(errorMessage); //There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.

          callback(error);
        });
    }


...


function logoutUser(){
    firebase.auth().signOut()
        .then(() => {
            return null;
      // Sign-out successful.
    })
        .catch((error) => {
            return error;
      // An error happened.
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you by any chance using sessions? If so, the framework might set the headers for the session cookie, and send them before you trying to set them.

Comment: @Dan hi! No, I'm not using sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `response.render(...)` more then once will cause this error.

Solution is to remove the second render call so these 2 lines:

```
response.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
response.render('index');
```

So it should look like this:

```
app.get('/user', (request, response) => {
    userService.checkUser( (firebaseUser) => {
        if (firebaseUser) {
            response.render('user', {firebaseUser});
        }else {
            response.redirect('/');
        }
        // what is the bellow code even for??
        // above you either render user page
        // or redirect to /
        // response.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
        // response.render('index');
    });
});
```

Comment: hi @Molda, thankyou for the reply, after aplying your solution I'm getting another error, I edited my question.

Comment: Can you add the code for `app.get('/logout',..` to you question. Or maybe just check you don't call render function twice in there.

Comment: I've added all the functions that I didn't post before, I hope it is helpfull

Comment: I can't see any issue with the logout. It's hard to help. But the error is the same which means you are calling some of the response's functions twice. Those can be render, send, json, redirect, sendFile or sendStatus.